# Perl: Searching a file

Tags: perl

I am creating a perl script that takes in the a file (example ./prog file)
I need to parse through the file and search for a string. This is what I thought would work, but it does not seem to work. The file is one work per line containing 50 lines

```
@array = < >;   
    print "Enter the word you what to match\n";
    chomp($match = <STDIN>);        

    foreach $line (@array){
        if($match eq $line){
            print "The word is a match";
            exit
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible the string spans two lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're chomping your user input, but not the lines from the file.

They can't match; one ends with `\n` the other does not. Getting rid of your `chomp` should solve the problem. (Or, adding a `chomp($line)` to your loop).

```
$match = <STDIN>;
```

**or**

```
foreach $line (@array){
    chomp($line);
    if($match eq $line){
        print "The word is a match";
        exit;
    }
}
```

**Edit in the hope that the OP notices his mistake from the comments below:**

Changing `eq` to `==` doesn't "fix" anything; it breaks it. You need to use `eq` for string comparison. You need to do one of the above to fix your code.

```
$a = "foo\n"; 
$b = "bar"; 
print "yup\n" if ($a == $b);
```

Output:

> yup

Comment: So go without the chomp on the user input and chomp @array. I thought that the <> operator reads in the file and does all of the n\

Comment: Either chomp both or neither. `@array = < >;` does *not* remove newlines.

Comment: So I add the chomp to my loop $match eq chomp($line). But when I run it it does not seem to run the if( $match eq chomp($line))

Comment: [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) can work on a list as well. For example: `chomp @array`.

Comment: @AlanHaggaiAlavi - true, but by doing it in the loop on each element you don't chomp things that you don't need to in the case of finding a match prior to the last element.

Comment: @jenglee - **no**, you didn't. Using `==` is incorrect and you will find that things that shouldn't match suddenly do. See my edit to my answer.

Comment: @BrianRoach I am trying to follow the changes with chomp($line) but when I run the code it does not seem to find the input, even though I know it is there